# How fast does the web fluid exit Spider-Man's web shooters?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

As I was watching Spider-Man swing and grab, swing and grab, as he traveled post haste across the big screen, I thought his commute time was quite impressive.

How fast does the web fluid exit from his web shooters?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the movie, let's say that his maximum shot range is about 100 meters. That's about 30 stories, so it's not wrong by a factor of 10. And let's say that it takes about 1/10 of a second for the web to reach its target. Again, that's not off by a factor of 10.

So 100 meters in 1/10 of a second needs a velocity of 1000 m/sec. If you want to do your own math, you can refer to the Wiki page for [the speed of sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound). But basically, that's Mach 3, or just about the speed of an M16 bullet.

Within a factor of 10 or so.

Comment: +1 Lots of people that do mathy things on YouTube have also done things like measured video game pixels and whatnot and all come up with similar conclusions. The web should instantly kill any person Spider-Man gets a direct shot on and/or sticks to a wall from sheer g-forces.

Comment: @phyrfox - Mmmm. Well, no, not necessarily. The question of the density and amount of web material used has not been addressed. if the stuff is unreasonably light, recoil and impact become a non-issue. At the price of making the maximum throw unusably short. Aerodynamic friction will slow down the web stream. Which requires a higher ejection velocity which increases recoil and impact ....

Comment: Interesting - so there should really be a sonic boom crack like that of a high velocity bullet when he uses his web shooters...